# Задержка в выводе текста

Tags: javascript

При нажимании на клавишу - должно выводить в консоль содержимое поля ввода, но на самом деле выводит на один символ меньше, чем нужно.

```
 document.onkeypress = function(){ 
        var text = document.getElementsByClassName("im_editable im-chat-input--text _im_text");
        var input = text[0].innerText;
        console.log(input);
}
```

Пример: вводится "Привет" - выводится "Приве".

Comment: символ еще не в `innerText`. Используйте `keyup`.

Comment: @igor спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cимвол еще не записался в элемент. Используйте `keyup`.

```js
document.querySelector("textarea").onkeypress = function() {
  console.log("keypress: " + document.querySelector("textarea").value);
}
document.querySelector("textarea").onkeyup = function() {
  console.log("keyup: " + document.querySelector("textarea").value);
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Спасибо, хорошо работает через keyup